# Can the "one" be omitted in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

> For me, the price is higher than the one for him.

I know "For me, the price is higher than him." must be wrong.

But what is the most simplified version of this sentence? Can I also omit "the one" and leave just "For me, the price is higher than for him."?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth reading; https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Conversational%20Deletion%20is%3aa

Comment: His price is lower than mine. My price is higher than his.

Comment: A bette way of saying it is: "The price for me is higher than the one for him."  Here, "the one" refers to "price"--the sentence could be "The price for me is higher than the price for him." You could say "They charge him more" -- but there is no way to shorten the sentence otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The best sentence that expresses what you want to express, is "He may be able to afford it at the current price, but i can not". But if you are saying "Why am I being charged more" then use this one "Why am I being charged more than him/he is".

Comment: While those are nice suggestions, I don't think you answered OP's question at all.

Comment: **It turns out that *“He may afford it”* is ungrammatical**in English. You would instead need to say either *“He may be able to afford it”* or *“He might be able to do afford it”*, or possibly *“He can afford it”*.

Comment: That is because the question is not very clear

Comment: @sardikuka You are correct that it is not a very clear question.